# How to project all nested documents from an array of objects?

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a document like this:

```
{
        "_id": "5ffc130e9fb31b26162e0bad",
        "results": [
            {
                "customer": {
                    "display_name": "Manno Dispensary - first",
                    "ext_acct_id": "267"
                }
            },
            {
                "customer": {
                    "display_name": "Manno Dispensary - second",
                    "ext_acct_id": "262"
                }
            },
            {
                "customer": {
                    "display_name": "Kako Dispensary - first",
                    "ext_acct_id": "261"
                }
            },
            {
                "customer": {
                    "display_name": "Kako Dispensary - second",
                    "ext_acct_id": "263"
                }
            }
        ]
}
```

I want to write a MongoDB query which does a regex search on `"customer.display_name"` and returns all those documents in results that satisfies this criteria.

I have written this query till now, and it returns me the desired output, but the problem is, it is only retuning one document inside results, Am I missing anything in this?

my desired output:

```
{
            "_id": "5ffc130e9fb31b26162e0bad",
            "results": [
                {
                    "customer": {
                        "display_name": "Manno Dispensary - first",
                        "ext_acct_id": "267"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "customer": {
                        "display_name": "Manno Dispensary - second",
                        "ext_acct_id": "262"
                    }
                }
            ]
    }
```

What I am actually getting:

```
{
                "_id": "5ffc130e9fb31b26162e0bad",
                "results": [
                    {
                        "customer": {
                            "display_name": "Manno Dispensary - first",
                            "ext_acct_id": "267"
                        }
                    }
                ]
        }
```

this is the query which I have written to fetch all customers which contain "Manno" in their customer name.

My collection name is Order(mongoose), search="Manno"

```
Order.find({
      results: {
        $elemMatch : {
          "customer.display_name": {$regex: search}
        }
      }
    },{
      results: {
        $elemMatch : {
          "customer.display_name": {$regex: search}
        }
      } 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$elemMatch` and `$` will return only single matching document/object form array, try [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) and [$regexMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexMatch/index.html),

- `$filter` to iterate loop of results array
- `$regexMatch` to check regular expression condition, it will return true or false

```
Order.find({
  results: {
    $elemMatch: {
      "customer.display_name": { $regex: "Manno" }
    }
  }
},
{
  results: {
    $filter: {
      input: "$results",
      cond: {
        $regexMatch: {
          input: "$$this.customer.display_name",
          regex: "Manno"
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3iYem0O4PJI)

Comment: didn't work for me. finally, I changed the database schema and made a new query